# Can a React app have components in different JS files without a build system?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

React examples use gulp, Grunt, or npm and Browserify or Webpack. In the code below I have a React app without those, and I am just wondering if this last step is possible.

An HTML page that pulls in React, babel-browser, and one JavaScript file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.0/dist/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.0/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" src="js/App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is `App.js`

```js
'use strict';
var {
  Component
} = React;
class Hdr extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<header className="container">Header</header>);
  }
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Hdr />
      </main>
    );
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

The `App` component pulls in the `Hdr` component. Here is the question: how can I put the `Hdr` in a separate JS file? I tried it, and `App` cannot find `Hdr`.

[Here is a working demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/dzcn7gta1l2y63MZvPCX/preview).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Pw75IIuonyz9UlBhvWo5?p=preview

You just have to do

```
window.Hdr = Hdr
```

And it will work.

**Edit :** Based on Joshua's comment

```
window.__MyApp__ = {
   // a lot of app props
}
window.__MyApp__.Hdr = Hdr
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me in the plnkr. I had seen this answer before but wasn't sure where in the files to add it.

Comment: Just for general stability you might want to namespace anything you put on the global window object, e.g. `window.__MyAppName__ = window.__MyAppName__ || {};` `window.__MyAppName__.Hdr = Hdr`

Answer (score 0):

you can load your js file in app like any other script. But I would advise you use requirejs it would be cleaner.

Comment: Simply loading JS files is not working. Can you please share a plnkr using requireJS ?